# Use id as a normal column in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

So basically I have 2 problems.

Firstly I would like to use the column named "article_id" as the primary key for my articles table. It is setup as an auto_increment primary key in my database.

Secondly I also need to use the column named "id" as a standard column.

Now what is happening is that when I assign a value to "id", "article_id" is also being populated with the same value. Ideally "article_id" should remain empty so that when the record is inserted it is given a generated auto_increment value. I should also note that I need to utilize the column named "type" so that is why I have overwritten the inheritance_column.

Here is my current model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :id
  attr_reader :type

  set_primary_key :article_id

  set_inheritance_column do
    'active_record_type'
  end

  def id=(id)
    @id = id
  end
end
```

And it is being populated with the following code

```
article = Article.new
article.type = 123
article.name = 'Foo Bar'
article.id   = 456
article.save
```

So basically how can I get the above code to generate a query that looks like

```
INSERT INTO `articles` (`type`, `name`, `id`) VALUES(123, 'Foo Bar', 456)
```

But currently it is generating a query that looks like

```
INSERT INTO `articles` (`type`, `name`, `id`, `article_id`) VALUES(123, 'Foo Bar', 456, 456)
```

Comment: is article_id an auto increment?

Comment: yes article_id is an auto_increment primary key in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :article_id

  def id
    self.read_attribute(:id)
  end

  def id=(id)
    self.write_attribute(:id, id)
  end
end
```

---

```
>> a = Article.new
>> a.id = 111
>> a.name = "First"
>> a.save
  Article Create (0.6ms)   INSERT INTO "articles" ("name", "id") VALUES('First', 111)
>> Article.all
=> [#<Article article_id: 5, id: 111, name: "First">]
>> Article.first.id
=> 111
>> Article.first.article_id
=> 5
```

Comment: At least for rails 4, I needed to use _read_attribute instead